# Upload all excel sheet data to google sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in an excel sheet which i have put in a google sheet for reference [sheet_link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y2CQmnzjq9T_93Z3ihUWiBEgzZA8yigYIWdLVoYVzGo/edit?pli=1#gid=0)
**Excel sheet values** contains the data to be upload to the google sheet, **Current O/p** contains the data which is uploading in present (i.e only TB column is uploading) and **Expected O/p** contains the expected output. I want all columns data which is present in **Excel sheet values** to be upload into google sheet.

I tried below code:

```
sheet2 = client.open("Dashboard name").worksheet('W1')

pivot = filtered_data.pivot_table(index=['Account ID','Account Name','Contract ID','Code Value'], values=['TB','Account ID','Account Name','Contract ID','Code Value'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
pivot.ffill(inplace=True)

pivot.reset_index().to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Work_Sheet2',index=False)

t1 = pivot.values.tolist()
fc = sheet2.col_values(1)
rs = len(fc)+1
sheet2.insert_rows(t1,rs)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a service account on google cloud.
Go to `console.cloud.google.com`, and write: `IAM and admin` in the search bar. Then go to the `Service account` subtab. Click on `CREATE SERVICE ACCOUNT`, Please find the image below as a reference:

[image]

Choose a name, then click `Done`. After that, click on the key you created and navigate to the `KEYS` section:

[image]

Click the following: `ADD KEY` -> `Create New Key` -> `JSON format`.
Once you do these steps, a JSON file is stored on your machine.
copy, and store it in the same directory with your code (I named it **google_credentials.json**).

Now you could use this sample code after you impute your files names instead of these *EXCEL_TO_READ_FROM* and *URL_OF_THE_GOOGLE_SHEET*:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd

# Set up the credentials for accessing the Google Sheet
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('google_credentials.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# Open the Google Sheet
sh = gc.open_by_url("URL_OF_THE_GOOGLE_SHEET")
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

# Read the data from the Excel sheet
df = pd.read_excel('EXCEL_TO_READ_FROM.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Upload the data to the Google Sheet
worksheet.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())
```

> Note: I assumed you already created a Google sheet empty file and you are
> trying to fill it

Comment: Hi Ali,

I have used the above code which you have given, still I am getting same output. Only TB column is getting uploaded to google sheet. I want to upload all 5 columns to google sheet.